# NSIS Installer Rebuild

Tags: installation, nsis, rebuild

I have about 100 compiled NSIS installers without the corresponding script and I would like to exchange 3 files inside all the installers.

I'm able to extract the content of the installers using 7zip but it's not possible to recreate the executable with the exchanged files.

Is there any tool to exchange files inside a NSIS installer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a tool exists.

There was a old version of 7zip that tried to decompile the script as well but it could not fully reconstruct the source script.